# Dynamic webflow configuration

Tags: spring-webflow

Is there any way to update the webflow configuration and reload it to make impact on the flow of web application on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

So you want webflow to dynamically pick up changes made to your flow definitions? WebFlow 2 added support for this, specify "development="true" in your flow-builder-services, like this:

```
<flow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices"
                                view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator"
                                conversion-service="customConversionService"
                                development="true"/>
```

This is the section from the docs:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#flow-registry-builder-services

> **development**:
>   Set this to true to switch on flow development mode. Development mode switches on hot-reloading of flow definition changes, including changes to dependent flow resources such as message bundles.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean webflow configuration flow definitions xml, you can put them into WEB-INF folder. Here you can update them and application will use actual version.